# HTML Signature Images not showing in Gmail Mobile app (IOS)

Tags: html, image, html-email, email-client

Working on an HTML Email signature and I've got everything working for most necessary clients, mobile and desktop. The only issue I'm running into is with the Gmail App for mobile (I'm using it on iOS 10). The images will not load on the Gmail app and I'm unsure as to why.

[Image as it appears on Gmail Mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z19Sp.jpg)

[image]

The code for my images are all the same (There are 5 total, 1 logo, and 4 social media icons).

```
<img src="image-source" height="133" width="275" style="border: none; width: 275px; max-width: 275px !important; height: 133px; max-height: 133px !important; color: #33424d; font-size: 20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;" alt="Alt Text" title="logo">
```

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to figure out why this is only happening on the mobile app itself. Any idea what could be causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems the images are blocked or something? Is the image path visible in dev tools? also please add in the code for the signature so we can see more of what the signature holds and if there is any errors in your method of coding.

Comment: It appears to be due to Gmail's spam filter. I sent the signature through using a different email account and it worked just fine. Now it's giving me some odd display error but that's a different question entirely. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this issue is due to Gmail's spam filter. My email account from my own domain is fairly new so Gmail sends all mail from this account to spam, even though I labelled it not spam it still blocked the images.

When I tested the signature by sending from a more established email it appears to display the images properly.